# Add Muted Users in a database? When they rejoin they get the role again

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def mute(self, ctx, member:discord.Member, *, time: TimeConverter = None):
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted by ez")
        if not role:
            role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Muted by ez")

            for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
                await channel.set_permissions(role, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True,
                                              read_messages=False)
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await asyncio.sleep(time)
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(f"Muted {member.mention} for {time}s")
        else:
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(f"Muted {member.mention} for {time}s")
            await asyncio.sleep(time)
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(f'Unmuted {member.mention}')


    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def unmute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted by ez")
        await member.remove_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f'Unmuted {member.mention}')
```

this my code so far its perfectly working, but i am so long in tht and ask myself how to add users in json database so when they rejoin they still have the role.

**Update better code**
i got now all ur chanches but not these with more data:
i want to add guild id, mute duration and author id

so i tried to store tht all but i got many errors so i hope u can help me again
this my code so far

```
import re

import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import cogs._json
time_regex = re.compile("(?:(\d{1,5})(h|s|m|d))+?")
time_dict = {"h": 3600, "s": 1, "m": 60, "d": 86400}



class TimeConverter(commands.Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, argument):
        args = argument.lower()
        matches = re.findall(time_regex, args)
        time = 0
        for key, value in matches:
            try:
                time += time_dict[value] * float(key)
            except KeyError:
                raise commands.BadArgument(
                    f"{value} is an invalid time key! h|m|s|d are valid arguments"
                )
            except ValueError:
                raise commands.BadArgument(f"{key} is not a number!")
        return round(time)


class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(
        name='mute',
        description="Mutes a given user for x time!",
        ussage='<user> [time]'
    )
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, time: TimeConverter= None):
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted by ez")
        if not role:
            role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Muted by ez", colour=0x171717)

            for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
                await channel.set_permissions(role, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True,
                                              read_messages=False, add_reactions=False)
            pass

        try:

                data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
                if member.id in data['muted_users']:
                    remsg = await ctx.send("reloading the mute")
                    await member.remove_roles(role)
                    data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
                    data["muted_users"].remove(member.id)
                    cogs._json.write_json(data, "muted_users")
                    await asyncio.sleep(2)
                    await remsg.edit(content=f"Unmuted `{member}`")
                    data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
                    data["muted_users"].append(member.id)
                    cogs._json.write_json(data, "muted_users")
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    if not time:
                        await asyncio.sleep(2)
                        await remsg.edit(content=f"Muted `{member}`")
                    else:
                        await asyncio.sleep(2)
                        await remsg.edit(content=f"Muted `{member}` for `{time}s`")

                        await asyncio.sleep(time)
                        await member.remove_roles(role)
                        data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
                        data["muted_users"].remove(member.id)
                        cogs._json.write_json(data, "muted_users")
                        await ctx.send(content=f"Unmuted `{member}`")


                    return
        except KeyError:
            pass
        data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
        data["muted_users"].append(member.id)
        cogs._json.write_json(data, "muted_users")
        await member.add_roles(role)

        if not time:
            await ctx.send(f"Muted `{member}`")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Muted `{member}`for `{time}s`")
            await asyncio.sleep(time)
            print(time)
            if role in member.roles:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
                data["muted_users"].remove(member.id)
                cogs._json.write_json(data, "muted_users")
                await ctx.send(f"Unmuted `{member}`")
            else:
                data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
                data["muted_users"].remove(member.id)
                cogs._json.write_json(data, "muted_users")

    @commands.command(
        name='unmute',
        description="Unmuted a member!",
        usage='<user>'
    )
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def unmute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted by ez")
        if not role:
            role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Muted by ez", color=0x171717)

            for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
                await channel.set_permissions(role, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True,
                                              read_messages=False, add_reactions=False)
            return

        if role not in member.roles:
            await ctx.send("This member is not muted.")
            data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
            data["muted_users"].remove(member.id)
            cogs._json.write_json(data, "muted_users")





        await member.remove_roles(role)
        data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
        data["muted_users"].remove(member.id)
        cogs._json.write_json(data, "muted_users")
        await ctx.send(f"Unmuted `{member}`")
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))
```

that is the cog

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

def get_path():
    """
    A function to get the current path to bot.py

    Returns:
     - cwd (string) : Path to bot.py directory
    """
    cwd = Path(__file__).parents[1]
    cwd = str(cwd)
    return cwd

def read_json(filename):
    """
    A function to read a json file and return the data.

    Params:
     - filename (string) : The name of the file to open

    Returns:
     - data (dict) : A dict of the data in the file
    """
    cwd = get_path()
    with open(cwd+'/bot_config/'+filename+'.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    return data

def write_json(data, filename):
    """
    A function used to write data to a json file

    Params:
     - data (dict) : The data to write to the file
     - filename (string) : The name of the file to write to
    """
    cwd = get_path()
    with open(cwd+'/bot_config/'+filename+'.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

my "converting file"

```
{
    "muted_users": []
}
```

my json store file

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        print(member)
        await member.send("hello")
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Muted by ez")
        data = cogs._json.read_json("muted_users")
        if member.id in data['muted_users']:
            await member.add_roles(role)
```

and my on_member_join module.
This code is fully working but i want to make it better, bcs like in the on member join module is could be tht one member so the same kid is muted on one server and not on the other but gets the mute on both. thats why i need the guild id.
and how can i remove all tht data when i unmute the member again?
i didnt understand tht so can u help me again?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow steps will be as follows

1. When command is used, collect the user data
2. store it to a json file, using the unique user id as key is preferred.
3. When a new member is joined, check for the user id under json data
4. If the id exists in json data, assign the muted role to them, otherwise pass.

---

### Useful resources

- [Python json lib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)
- [`discord.on_member_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join)

---

### Example of storing the data

```py
import json
...

class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    ...

    @commands.command()
    async def mute(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
        ...
        # add the muted role
        await member.add_roles(role)

        # open the json file and add the data
        with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
            if member.id not in data['muted']:
                data['muted'].append(member.id)
                json.dump(data, fp)
        ...
```

create a JSON file named `users.json` with the following data:

```json
{
    "muted": []
}
```

in this simple example, the muted users are stored as in a list. The generated JSON file will look as following:

```json
{
    "muted": [123123123, 1231231231, 23423423423]
}
```

---

### Example for checking the user is in list

```py
import json
...

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    ...
    with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
        if member.id in data['muted']:
            await member.add_roles(role)

...
```

## Edit: Storing More Data

This edit is for answering part of the question received in the comments

In order to collect more data, you can use dictionaries instead of a single list. A possibility of the JSON data structure you are going for can be as follows

```json
{
    "guild_1_id": {
        "user_1_id": {
            "channel": "12345678",
            "moderator": "12345678"
        },
        "user_2_id": {
            "channel": "12345678",
            "moderator": "12345678"
        },
        ...
    },
    "guild_2_id": {
        "user_1_id": {
            "channel": "12345678",
            "moderator": "12345678"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

First, collect all the data you need, store it in a dictionary under the member's ID

```py
newdata = {
    member.id: {
        "channel": ctx.channel.id,
        "moderator": ctx.author.id
    }
}
```

When updating the JSON data, check if the guild ID exists in it, if yes then update the data of the server to include the new member's data, otherwise create a new key with guild ID and assign the new member's data to it.

The modified version look as following

```py
# open the json file and add the data
with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
    if ctx.guild.id not in data.keys():
        data[ctx.guild.id] = newdata
    else:
        data[ctx.guild.id].update(newdata)
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

Combining them, you have this

```py
import json
...

class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    ...

    @commands.command()
    async def mute(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
        ...
        await member.add_roles(role)

        newdata = {
            member.id: {
                "channel": ctx.channel.id,
                "moderator": ctx.author.id
            }
        }

        # open the json file and add the data
        with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
            if ctx.guild.id not in data.keys():
                data[ctx.guild.id] = newdata
            else:
                data[ctx.guild.id].update(newdata)
            json.dump(data, fp)
        ...
```

Now modify your member data checking in the `on_member_join` to

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    ...
    with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
        if member.id in data[member.guild.id].keys():
            await member.add_roles(role)

            # further data can be accessed as following
            user_data = data[member.guild.id][member.id]
            
            channel = user_data['channel']
            moderator = user_data['moderator']
...
```

---

### Also check

- [Realpython article on JSON](https://realpython.com/python-json/)

Comment: first of all ty so much, i got it now stored but how i have to do it when i would like to store more data like channel id guild id or author id do i have more options to data or how is this working?

Comment: @Socsz I have updated my answer to include further details on how you can store more data, please check again :)

Comment: bro thank u so much for ur help, but i didnt understand so right i added some more details to my question so i hope u can help